# Preventing Application scale from cutting off button labels in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I've encountered a problem that's driving me nuts. Apparently button labels do not scale appropriately in flex or I'm just not going about it correctly. A simple runnable test case is below.

The issue: [image: The Issue]

In the test case you can see that the button label is cut off at the end at multiple different window sizes but sometimes it "pops" into a new font level it seems and it looks correct? Why is this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"> 
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            public var minScale:Number = 0.5;
            public var baseWidth:Number = 1000;
            public var baseHeight:Number = 800;

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);

                if(width < baseWidth || height < baseHeight) {
                    var sx:Number = Math.max(minScale, width / baseWidth);
                    var sy:Number = Math.max(minScale, height / baseHeight);

                    var s:Number = Math.min( sx, sy );

                    getChildAt(0).scaleX = s;
                    getChildAt(0).scaleY = s;
                }
                else{
                    getChildAt(0).scaleX = 1;
                    getChildAt(0).scaleY = 1;
                }   
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Button label="WWWWWWW" fontSize="12"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found this which seems really similar but I'd like to avoid using a graphical skin to show text? http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=150938

Comment: Is your font embedded? If not, it might not scale. However, if you don't want to embed the font, in some cases you can make it scale by setting blendMode to "layer." But you need to make sure it is scaling to the same percentage both x & y.

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html) on embedding fonts and I still had the issue. I also tried the blendMode layer as you suggested. As you can see in my code block above I'm using the same scale for the X & Y already. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: On a side note, I also played with the skinning of the button but the resizing of a graphical skin on a button looks like garbage? I'm not a graphical designer though so I don't know if there's any fancy tricks to this to get it to be vectorized properly.

Comment: Did you use 9-slice scaling?

Comment: Also, are you certain sure that the child at 0 is a button and not, for example, the default gradient graphics that gave Flex 3 applications their characteristic gradient?

Comment: BTW, is it at all possible that using a [scaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) of SHOW_ALL could maybe do the trick with fewer code acrobatics?

Comment: You'd think something as simple as text in a button with a scaling would be fairly straight-forward... I'll give all those things a shot and report back. (tried to even say the hell with it and make the button huge but it still has it's text field cut off!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After code review, detected that when you scale canvas, button not update display list, and button call intresting method for  textField: truncateToFit(); For fix bug, create custom Button class, and override updateDisplayList method:

```
package classes
{
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.core.IUITextField;
    import mx.core.UITextField;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;

    public class ButtonScale extends Button
    {
        public function ButtonScale()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var tf:IUITextField = mx_internal::getTextField() as IUITextField;
            tf.width = tf.textWidth + UITextField.mx_internal::TEXT_WIDTH_PADDING;
        }
    }
}
```

When you will scale, call button.invalidateDisplayList(), or create custon Canvas:

```
package classes
{
    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class CanvasScale extends Canvas
    {
        public function CanvasScale()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function set scaleX(value:Number):void
        {
            super.scaleX = value;

            for (var i:uint = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
            {
                UIComponent(getChildAt(i)).invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:classes="classes.*"> 
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
            import mx.core.IUITextField;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            public var minScale:Number = 0.5;
            public var baseWidth:Number = 900;
            public var baseHeight:Number = 700;

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);

                var child:UIComponent = getChildAt(0) as UIComponent;

                if(width < baseWidth || height < baseHeight) 
                {
                    var sx:Number = Math.max(minScale, width / baseWidth);
                    var sy:Number = Math.max(minScale, height / baseHeight);

                    var s:Number = Math.min( sx, sy );

                    child.scaleX = s;
                    child.scaleY = s;
                }
                else
                {

                    child.scaleX = 1;
                    child.scaleY = 1;
                }   
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <classes:CanvasScale>
        <classes:ButtonScale label="WWWWWWW" fontSize="12" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10"/>
    </classes:CanvasScale>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for my case. I tried it in an HBox too for kicks and noticed the problem reoccurred. I'm guessing this is a fundamental problem in how flex handles scaling so any parent containers will need to be extended.

Comment: Warning to others implementing this fix, blendMode=layer seems to override these changes.